# Failed sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

Tags: react-native, macos, cocoapods, ffi

In my react native app, I tried to install ffi using "sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi" but it's always failed and return following error.

```
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20221214-80226-arassj.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I'm using MacBook Air M1 2020

Comment: which configuration of PC you are using?

Comment: Mabook Air M1 2020

Comment: ```https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/286``` Check this document it might be help you.

Comment: try this command: ```brew install cocoapods```

Comment: @darshilsakhiya it worked for me with some extra configs in zsh terminal. Thanks again for saving my time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/286 Check this document it might be help you and also try this command:

> brew install cocoapods

Comment: Hi @Ruchira Swarnapriya can you please accept this answer so It will help others also.